# Symfony/Doctrine : persistentCollection error

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a problem when displaying a table on twig. Let me explain, I have two User and Role entities which are linked with a ManyToMany relation, so I have a user_role pivot table. The problem is that when I want to display the table of users with their roles in a table I get the error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class
>   Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string").

Here is the code for User.php

```
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
/**
* @ORM\Id()
* @ORM\GeneratedValue()
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
*/
private $id;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
*/
private $username;

/**
* @var string The hashed password
* @ORM\Column(type="string")
*/
private $password;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=false, options={"default" : 0})
*/
private $isActive;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true, length=64)
*/
private $token;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
*/
private $expiresAt;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users", fetch="LAZY")
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_role",
* joinColumns={
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
* },
* inverseJoinColumns={
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
* }
* )
*
*/
private $roles = [];

public function __construct()
{
$this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getId(): ?int
{
return $this->id;
}

/**
* A visual identifier that represents this user.
*
* @see UserInterface
*/
public function getUsername(): string
{
return (string)$this->username;
}

public function setUsername(string $username): self
{
$this->username = $username;

return $this;
}

/**
* @inheritDoc
*/
public function getRoles(): array //array return
{
$roles[] = $this->roles;
var_dump($roles);

// Afin d'être sûr qu'un user a toujours au moins 1 rôle
if (empty($roles)) {
$roles[] = 'ROLE_ADMIN';
}

return $roles;
}


/**
* @see UserInterface
*/
public function getPassword(): string
{
return (string)$this->password;
}

public function setPassword(string $password): self
{
$this->password = $password;

return $this;
}

/**
* @see UserInterface
*/
public function getSalt()
{
// not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm in security.yaml
}

/**
* @see UserInterface
*/
public function eraseCredentials()
{
// If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
// $this->plainPassword = null;
}

public function getIsActive(): ?bool
{
return $this->isActive;
}

public function setIsActive(bool $isActive): self
{
$this->isActive = $isActive;

return $this;
}

public function getToken(): ?string
{
return $this->token;
}

public function setToken(string $token): self
{
$this->token = $token;

return $this;
}

public function getExpiresAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
{
return $this->expiresAt;
}

public function setExpiresAt(\DateTimeInterface $expiresAt): self
{
$this->expiresAt = $expiresAt;

return $this;
}

public function isExpired(): bool
{
return $this->getExpiresAt() <= new \DateTime();
}

public function createToken()
{
return substr(str_replace(['+', '/'], ['-', '_'], base64_encode(random_bytes(50))), 0, 63);
}

public function setRoles($roles)
{
if (is_array($roles)) {
$this->roles = $roles;
} else {
$this->roles->clear();
$this->roles->add($roles);
}
return $this;
}

/**
* Add userRoles
*
* @param \App\Entity\Role $roles
* @return User
*/
public function addRoles(\App\Entity\Role $roles)
{
$this->roles[] = $roles;

return $this;
}


/**
* Remove userRoles
*
* @param \App\Entity\Role $roles
*/
public function removeRoles(\App\Entity\Role $roles)
{
$this->roles->removeElement($roles);
}

/**
* String representation of object
* @link https://php.net/manual/en/serializable.serialize.php
* @return string the string representation of the object or null
* Transform object to string
*/
public function serialize()
{
return serialize([
$this->id,
$this->username,
$this->password,
$this->isActive,
$this->token,
$this->expiresAt,
$this->roles
]);
}

/**
* @param string $serialized
* Transform string to object
*/
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
list(
$this->id,
$this->username,
$this->password,
$this->isActive,
$this->token,
$this->expiresAt
) = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
}
```

And here is the code for Role.php

```
class Role implements \Serializable
{
/**
* @ORM\Id()
* @ORM\GeneratedValue()
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
*/
private $id;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
*/
private $name;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
*/
private $description;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="roles")
*/
private $users = [];

public function __construct()
{
$this->users = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getId(): ?int
{
return $this->id;
}

public function getName(): ?string
{
return $this->name;

}

public function setName($name)
{
$this->name = $name;

return $this;
}

public function getDescription(): ?string
{
return $this->description;
}

public function setDescription(string $description): self
{
$this->description = $description;

return $this;
}

/*
* methods for RoleInterface
*/
/*public function getRoles()
{
return $this->getName();
}*/

/**
* Add users
*
* @param \App\Entity\User $users
* @return Role
*/
public function addUser(\App\Entity\User $users)
{
$this->users[] = $users;

return $this;
}

/**
* Remove users
*
* @param \App\Entity\User $users
*/
public function removeUser(App\Entity\User $users)
{
$this->users->removeElement($users);
}

/**
* Get users
*
* @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
*/
public function getUsers()
{
return $this->users;
}

/**
* String representation of object
* @link https://php.net/manual/en/serializable.serialize.php
* @return string the string representation of the object or null
* Transform object to string
*/
public function serialize()
{
return serialize([
$this->id,
$this->name,
$this->description
]);
}

/**
* @param string $serialized
* Transform string to object
*/
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
list(
$this->id,
$this->name,
$this->description
) = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
}
 Ensuite dans mon controller j'ai fait un findAll()
/**
* @Route("/admin/user", name="admin_user_index")
* @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
*/
public function listUser(UserRepository $user)
{
return $this->render('admin/security_user/list_user.html.twig', ['user' => $user->findAll()]);
}
```

Then in my twig I get the data in an array

```
{% for list in user %}
   <TR>
<TD>{{ list.id }}</TD>
<TD>{{ list.username }}</TD>
<TD>{{ list.password }}</TD>
<TD>
{% for role in list.roles %}
               {{ role }}
           {% endfor %}

       </TD>
<TD>{{ list.isActive }}</TD>

<TD>
<a href="{{ path('admin_user_edit', {id: list.id}) }}" class="btn btn-secondary">Editer</a>
<form method="post" action="{{ path('admin_user_delete', {id: list.id}) }}" style="display: inline-block"
onsubmit="return confirm('Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer l\'utilisateur ?')">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token('delete' ~ list.id) }}">
<button class="btn btn-primary">Supprimer</button>
</form>
</TD>
</TR>
{% endfor %}
```

I would like to know how to look for role data instead of persistentCollection

If any of you can enlighten me, thank you in advance.

Comment: maybe replace `{{ role }}` by `{{ role.name }}`

Comment: I have already tried and this tells me that it does not exist

Comment: what doesn't exist?

Comment: Error : Neither the property "name" nor one of the methods "name()", "getname()"/"isname()"/"hasname()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection".

Comment: Should do a `{{ dump(role) }}` to verify what data you are fetching. At this point `role` is a `PersistentCollection` and not a `Role`

Comment: And why is it a persistent Collection ? I create a new Array Collection

Comment: You should add the output to the question, not as an answer. For your question, because you use doctrine to populate the `roles`

Comment: Really sorry, I just arrived on stack overflow.

Comment: The error comes from '$roles[] = $this->roles;' it needs to be '$roles = $this->roles;'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to had the inverse side on your User entity :

```php
// User.php

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
 */
$roles;

public function __construct()
{
    this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
}

// Generate Getter and Setter
...
```